# How do I send an ajax request to microsoft vision api?

Tags: javascript, ajax, azure-cognitive-services

I am following the documentation [here](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) and the sample code at the bottom looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
        "returnFaceId": "true",
        "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
        "returnFaceAttributes": "{age}",
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","REDACTED");
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: "http://newsrescue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/happy-person.jpg",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i keep getting error code 404 resource not found. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

A quick check with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) shows you're getting a bad parameter (not 404).

Couple of things:

1. `returnFaceAttributes` should be `"age"` (not `"{age}"`)
2. `data` needs a param name

Try this (check the `data` update):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <title>JSSample</title>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
        "returnFaceId": "true",
        "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
        "returnFaceAttributes": "age",
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","e2c75ad5d44846d590ac7c2dcc2f210e");
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: '{ "url": "http://newsrescue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/happy-person.jpg"}'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jisutegiwu/edit?html,console) to make sure it works (she's 19.3 years old according to Microsoft).

One last **important** note. Change your `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` key immediately!

Comment: With the need to use the subscription-key in every request, there's no way of doing this, securely, in javascript is there? You'd need your ajax call to hit a proxy web service that then makes this request server side right?

Comment: @JackMarchetti Correct. You could set up a backend (Node, Express, Django, ...) that makes the call for you and forwards the data.

Comment: so in serverless architectures how do they pull this off?

Comment: Environment variables. They will be injected into your environment. Check the docs for your serverless provider

Comment: but an azure function needs the function key passed within the header or within the query string. The call will fail before you even get to environment variables being injected.

Comment: Environment variables are available long before the call is made

Comment: If the function key is an environmental variable, how would that stop anyone from accessing the function if the function just loads the key from an environmental variable....how does that stop anyone?

Comment: They don't have access to the server. The server (AWS, GC, Azure) has your environment variables behind your login. They are sent to the code when the "server" is powered up. No one except the server can see it.

Comment: Right but if you have a serverless function that requires a key like in Azure, it won't even load unless the key is part of the request in a query string or header. So the environmental variable won't work.

Comment: Your serverless environment will inject it before spinning up the instance that will run your serverless function. Something still has to run that function